# Secret Manager for React JS application

Tags: reactjs, aws-secrets-manager

What is best way to manage client side secrets of React JS application. I am mostly getting below options when search-

1. .env file- I am already using it and want to use more secure option.
2. Secret Management Tools- its not possible to use services like aws secret manger at client side and its also possible with aws amplify.
3. Github Secret manager
4. Load secret at the time of deployment

Can someone please suggest flexible config management for React Js application.